# iOS UI Test: Wait for exist fails for dynamically added button

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, ui-testing, xcuitest

My application does a SDK auto update and initialization when it launches. When it completed I am adding a button to check if auto update and initialization are completed in my UI test:

```
let hiddenButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
hiddenButton.setTitle("databaseUpdated", for: .normal)
hiddenButton.accessibilityIdentifier = "databaseUpdated"
self.view.addSubview(hiddenButton)
```

I have tried following lines to check it but it always fails:

```
XCTAssertTrue(app.descendants(matching: .button)["databaseUpdated"].waitForExistence(timeout: 60))
XCTAssertTrue(app.children(matching: .button)["databaseUpdated"].waitForExistence(timeout: 60))
XCTAssertTrue(app.otherElements["databaseUpdated"].waitForExistence(timeout: 60))
XCTAssertTrue(app.buttons["databaseUpdated"].waitForExistence(timeout: 60))
```

I have confirmed that my button is in view hierarchy using `Debug View Hierarchy`:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I have decided to add the button in `viewDidLoad` with different identifier and update it when SDK is initialized:

```
private let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))

override public func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button.isAccessibilityElement = true
    button.accessibilityTraits = .button
    button.accessibilityIdentifier = "initial"
    view.addSubview(button)
}
```

when SDK is initialized it is set to:

```
button.accessibilityIdentifier = "databaseUpdated"
```

and here is what I see when I inspect the button in view debugger:

[image: accessibility attributes]

still test is failing to find it.

**UPDATE 2**

I am able to find the button using Accessibility Inspector:

[image: inspector]

Comment: Did you try to display your button by default and check if your test is working in that situation ? You can also try to look for a `staticText` instead of a button.

Comment: Check out my answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60361289

Comment: @cesarmarch yes I have tried that but didn't work.

Comment: And what on earth does “when SDK is initialized” mean?

Comment: When SDK is initialized means, the SDK I use, updates its database from internet every time my app is launches.

Comment: Try to set the accessibility identifier when you create the button.

Comment: @cesarmarch didn't you notice `hiddenButton.accessibilityIdentifier = "databaseUpdated"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the ViewController that you add the button is visible when you run the query. If not your query will fail.

Comment: When app is updating the SDK database the view controller running the update code is not yet visable on the screen.

Comment: I have moved my SDK update function to the root ViewController since SDK is using a shared instance and finally it worked and found the damn button. Thank you very much.